# JQuery DatePicker could not be interpreted as Date on Java

Tags: jsf, datepicker

Here is my DatePicker :

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
```

And the JSF input :

```
<h:inputText class="form-control" id="datenaissanceprofile" value="#{usermanagerMB.datenaissanceprofile}" maxlength="10">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

Java Date :

```
    public Date getDatenaissanceprofile() {
        return datenaissanceprofile;
    }
    public void setDatenaissanceprofile(Date datenaissanceprofile) {
        this.datenaissanceprofile = datenaissanceprofile;

//

user.setDatenaissanceprofile(getDatenaissanceprofile());
```

On submit of the registration form :

```
addUser:datenaissanceprofile : «04/21/2015» n’a pas pu être interprété en tant que date.
```

Which means :

```
addUser: datenaissanceprofile "04/21/2015" could not be interpreted as a date.
```

Does anyone know how to repare this ? the dateFormat of the DatePicker and JSF converter are both set, it should work no ? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this format is needed for you, then convert it into appropriate format before submitting.

Answer (score -1):

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

is for human readable *output*. You need to use a SimpleDateFormat and parse the input before you call your setter. Create a utility method that does the conversion and calls the setter and use that method in the UI.

```
public void setDatenaissanceprofileFromUi(String date){
    Date formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(date);
    setDatenaissanceprofile(formattedDate);
}
```

Also, make sure the SimpleDateFormat and input format match.

Comment: You're looking at the problem from a wrong angle. Look at the date formats once again.

Comment: Good pickup! The formats are dd/MM/yyyy, but the input is MM/dd/yyyy. I'll change my answer to reflect the actual input format.

Comment: Nope, the input is not `MM/dd/yyyy`. The input is `dd/mm/yyyy`. Moreover, `SimpleDateFormat` is unnecessary as this job is already done by `<f:convertDateTime>` (thus, it isn't for output only).